# SSH.NET - Disconnect after a few seconds without activity

Tags: vb.net, ssh

Good day

Greetings friends. This is the first time I ask a question in the forum ...

I am making an application for SSH connection with VB.Net 2015, for this I am using the SSH.NET library which works for me almost perfectly. When I launch the application connects excellent, I launch the first command and everything okay, but if I wait a few seconds the connection goes down, I have already set the timeout in 3 minutes and the KeepAliveInterval in 5 seconds and still the disconnection persists.

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Imports System.Text
Imports Renci.SshNet
Imports Renci.SshNet.Common

Public Class Form1

  Private oSshClient As SshClient
  Private oShellStream As ShellStream

  Private Delegate Sub RtbCallBack(ByVal sText As String)

  Private Sub SetRtbText(ByVal sText As String)

    If RichTextBox1.InvokeRequired Then

      RichTextBox1.Invoke(New RtbCallBack(AddressOf SetRtbText), {sText})
    Else

      RichTextBox1.AppendText(sText)
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Try

      oSshClient = New SshClient("x.x.x.x", 22, "user", "1234567890")
      oSshClient.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
      oSshClient.ConnectionInfo.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)
      oSshClient.Connect()

      If oSshClient.IsConnected Then

        oShellStream = oSshClient.CreateShellStream("oShellStream", 0, 0, 0, 0, 1024)

        AddHandler oSshClient.ErrorOccurred, AddressOf OnErrorOccurred
        AddHandler oShellStream.DataReceived, AddressOf OnDataReceived
      End If

    Catch ex As Exception

      Debug.Print("Código de Error: " & ex.HResult)

      If ex.HResult = -2146233088 Then

        MsgBox("Usuario y/o Password Incorrectos. Por favor Verifique...!",
               MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Mesaje del Sistema")

      Else
        MsgBox(ex.Message & vbCrLf & "Código de Error: " & ex.HResult,
               MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Mesaje del Sistema")
      End If

      If (oSshClient IsNot Nothing) Then

        oSshClient.Dispose()
        oSshClient = Nothing
      End If
    End Try
  End Sub

  Private Sub TextBox2_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyPress

    If Asc(e.KeyChar) = Keys.Enter Then

      e.Handled = True
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub TextBox2_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyDown

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then

      oShellStream.WriteLine(TextBox2.Text)
      TextBox2.Text = ""
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub OnErrorOccurred(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ExceptionEventArgs)

    SetRtbText(e.Exception.Message)
    MsgBox("Paso")
  End Sub

  Private Sub OnDataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ShellDataEventArgs)

    SetRtbText(Replace(Encoding.Default.GetString(e.Data), vbBack, ""))
  End Sub

  Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed

    If oSshClient IsNot Nothing Then

      oSshClient.Disconnect()
      oSshClient.Dispose()
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

Please help me with this detail which should be somewhat trivial.

Greetings and thank you very much

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant source code from your application.

Comment: The source code of the application was included